# Java instance returning via string input

Tags: java, class, object, syntax, instanceof

I want to shorten the length of this code:

```
public class PersonA {
    private HashMap<String, Object> attrs = new HashMap<>();
    public <T extends PersonAItem> T attr(String key, Class<T> var) {
         return (T) attrs.get(key);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    PersonA personA= new PersonA();
    String computerName = personA.attr("computer", Computer.class).getComputerName();

    System.out.printLn("person A has a " + computerName + " computer!");
}
```

The method

```
getComputerName();
```

is obviously unique to the computer class, therefore can only be called if the attr method returns the object as instanceof Computer.class. The problem is that to use the attr method, I have to input the string key and the class instance. I know that I can store this way:

```
private HashMap<Class <? extends PersonAItem>, Object> attrs = new HashMap<>();

public <T extends PersonAItem> T attr(Class<T> var) {
         return (T) attrs.get(var);
    }
```

and I would only need to input the class instance, but is there any way that I can ONLY input a string to return object instanceof Computer.class instead of just Object?

Obviously something like this:

```
public Object attr(String key) {
     if (key.equals("computer")
         return (Computer) attrs.get(key);
     return attrs.get(key);
}
```

would always return Object and never Computer.class

Is there any way that I can ONLY input a string to return object instanceof Computer.class instead of just Object?

Comment: Not really. You could just remove the `Class<T>` argument and unchecked cast the result to `T`, but `personA.attr("computer").getComputerName()` won't compile if you did that.

Comment: You could use the attribute class at the key in your map.

Comment: @Radiodef What object key would be used then? Would you then have to do personA.attrs.put(new Computer(), new Computer()); and then each time call it by creating a new computer instance? i.e personA.attr(new Computer()).getComputerName()? which would fail because u cant replicate the initial key

Comment: @teppic Already suggested that in the op...

Comment: @user7148508 sorry, I didn't read carefully enough

Comment: The possibility that I was referring to would be like `<T> T attr(String k) { return (T) attrs.get(k); }`.

Comment: then there no point in using T because its redundant, it will always just return Object